# How to implement a TreeView whose underlying data is a qvector<qvector<CustomClass>> data and can update the view whenever data is modified?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller

I have a data structure QVector < QVector< CustomClass>> called raw_data and I want to show it within a QTreeView in my Qt application, like the following graph:

```
\Index1
    |- raw_data[Index1][0]   // Assume my CustomClass can be convert ed to string
    |- raw_data[Index1][1]
    ...
    |- raw_data[Index1][N1-1]

\Index2
    |- raw_data[Index2][0]
    |- raw_data[Index2][1]
    ...
    |- raw_data[Index2][N2-1]
...
```

Here, raw_data can be modified by many other processing functions in my project and what I want to implement is updating the QTreeView automatically whenever some function has modified raw_data. (E.g. delete/insert)

I know model-view-controller is a solution for displaying underlying data in some view, but I don't really understand how to implement this.

Comment: When you change some data you should `emit dataChanged`. Also you should do all your changes thread-safe. And don't forget to emit `rowsAboutToBeInserted` + `rowsInserted`... when you modify data structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each views use a model to store the data. A Model is an abstraction for data in tables, lists, trees and each cell may store info of different properties like text, colors, states, etc.

To customize the model, you need to extends [QAbstractItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) or any of it derived classes. You may find more info about subclassing the model in [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-subclassing-reference).

To indicate the `View` that data has changed, your model need to emit [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) whenever any value (with visual impact) is modified.

Comment: Thanks, I've found this [Simple Tree Model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html), do you think it is a start point to implement my model?

Comment: It's certainly a good example. IMO the subclassing documentation is the best: create your tree structure, implement the model pure virtual function as they explain and you will end with a working model.

Comment: One more question, should I implement the SLOT of view or I just need to use functions like beginInsertItem() to send dataChanged signal?

Comment: You do not need to declare or connect the `signals/slots`, just `emit`. The `QAbstractItemModel` has already the declaration, and the `View` will connect automatically when you assign the model. The view do not need any changes, you could keep standard QTreeView

Comment: So, every time when I edit raw_data, e.g. raw_data.push_back(), I emit dataChanged?

Comment: No: dataChanged is when you modify a value. for new rows, you need the beforeInsertRow and afterInsertRow

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: YW. I suggest you to read carefully the documentation, there are other non-trivial aspects: management of the root element, meaning of invalid QModelIndex, return of columnCount when the model is empty, management of headers, etc..